# webGl Using loops for more draws - makes overlaping or deform geometry

Tags: webgl

I check `numberOfIndicesRender` it is 36 like usual.

Only first draw is normal :

```
 ...

// this draw always works fine
 world.GL.gl.drawElements(world.GL.gl[object.glDrawElements.mode], object.glDrawElements.numberOfIndicesRender, world.GL.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
// here is buggy
  object.instancedDraws.overrideDrawArraysInstance(object);

  this.mvPopMatrix(object.mvMatrix, this.mvMatrixStack);
```

[image]

```
 App.scene.tree1_.instancedDraws.overrideDrawArraysInstance =  function(object) {

    for (var i = 0; i < object.instancedDraws.numberOfInstance; i++) {

      object.instancedDraws.array_of_local_offset = [0 , 0, 18];
      mat4.translate(
        object.mvMatrix,
        object.mvMatrix,
        object.instancedDraws.array_of_local_offset
      );
      world.setMatrixUniforms(object, world.pMatrix, object.mvMatrix);

      world.GL.gl.drawArraysInstanced(
        world.GL.gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP,
        1,
        object.glDrawElements.numberOfIndicesRender,
        1
      );
   
    }

  };
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: appears like some buffer bindings are screwed up, I doubt anything more can be said with this little code, If you cant to find the problem you may update your question with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I found that it is not possible to draw with two different draw func . ( drawElements and drawArrays for example )  After drawElements (...)  work only drawElements (...) ....